# IntelliJ IDEA - Local Tomcat startup error - NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm trying to run tomcat 8.5.20 locally. It works on my colleagues PCs, but won't work on mine and we can't figure out why.

I can't find any solution for my error. Anything I try results in the following error.

```
WARN Error looking up JNDI resource [intname/properties/node.properties.file]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [intname/properties/node.properties.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [intname].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
```

It seams that it is not able to read the file or find the property in this file. But it is there, also in the copy of IntelliJ. I already tried to change relative path to absolute and vicaversa, but nothing changes.

I used different JDK Versions (1.8) and sometimes it gets past this error. But only 1 in 100 or so and I don't know why at this point.

Does anyone have any additional starting points I could try to get my local tomcat to run?